# Translation of Dellacherie's Capacités et Processus Stochastiques

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, translation

I have been studying the Strasbourg school's general theory of processes from Dellacherie and Meyer's *[Probabilities and Potential](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/north-holland-mathematics-studies/vol/29/suppl/C)*, and I really like it. I have heard very good reviews about another book by Dellacherie: *[Capacités et Processus Stochastiques](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-59107-9)*. Also this book gets cited frequently enough in other books (for example, Molchanov's *[Theory of Random Sets](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781849969499)*) that knowing its contents is necessary. Unfortunately, I cannot read French nor I am able to find an English translation of this work.

Since an English translation seems too much to hope for, I am requesting for a book which contains similar content (by this I mean similar scope; I know of many sources which treat classical theorems like Measurable projection and Section theorems but none which treat them for 200 pages like Dellacherie does) as *Capacités et Processus Stochastiques*.

If not, could someone fluent in French please translate the **contents of the book** and if possible provide an overview of what's covered?

Comment: The reviews in zbMATH and MathSciNet are both in English. Molchanov seems to cite the book for material that you could readily find somewhere else, such as the projection theorem.

Comment: is it legal to translate an entire book if you are not the copyright holder?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker By "contents of the book", I suspect the poster means not the entire book, but rather the contents pages.

Comment: a quite detailed overview of the contents of the book can be found at https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/blms/6.2.228